# Проверка существования файла

Tags: bash, linux

Нужен скрипт на bash, который принимает 1 параметр, т.е. я вызываю его

```
./script filename
```

а он проверяет, существует ли файл и выводит сообщение, что файл либо существует либо нет,
назвать его можно `exists.sh`.

Answer (score 11):

Внесу свои 5 копеек.

Вместо `[` можно использовать команду `test`:

```
if test -f "$FILE"; then  echo yes; fi
test -f "$FILE" && echo yes
```

и т. п.

Если глянуть на команды *nix повнимательней, то можно обнаружить:

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/web-agent$ which [
/usr/bin/[
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/web-agent$ which ] || echo no ']' in `uname`
no ] in Linux
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/web-agent$`
```

что `[` это команда (утилита), а `]` — просто украшательство (при пропуске которого /bin/bash и /bin/sh ругаются, но работают).

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/web-agent$ [ -f xaxa || echo no in ./
bash: [: пропущен ']'
no in ./
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/web-agent$ sh
$ [ -f xaxa || echo no in ./
sh: 1: [: missing ]
no in ./
$
```

Comment: Спасибо. Очень познавательно!

Comment: Кстати, несмотря на наличие утилиты `/usr/bin/[`, bash использует свою внутреннею реализацию. В этом можно убедиться выполнив:

    $ /usr/bin/[ --version
    [ (GNU coreutils) 8.14
    Упакован Gentoo (8.14 (p1))
    Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    ...

И:

    $ [ --version
    bash: [: пропущен `]'

Тоже самое относится к `test`, `true`, `false`, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Проверка осуществляется с помощью оператора ! и выражения -f

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1

if [ ! -f "$FILE" ]; then
    echo "Файл $FILE не существует"
fi
```

Подробнее здесь: [Introduction to if](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html).

Comment: Кстати,такой еще вопрос : как узнать указал ли вообще параметр? или неТ?

Comment: [ $# -eq 2 ] && .... - как вариант

Answer (score 6):

```
[ -f "$1" ] && echo "Существует" && exit 0
echo "Не суущесствует" && exit 1
```

Comment: Можно еще проще:

    [ -f $1 ] && echo "Существует" || echo "Не существует"

Answer (score 4):

Для решения подобных задач, иногда, удобно использовать однострочники на perl:

```
# perl -e 'if ($ARGV[0] && -e $ARGV[0]){print "Exists\n";} else {print "No\n";};' /i/1.txt
```

Exists

```
# perl -e 'if ($ARGV[0] && -e $ARGV[0]){print "Exists\n";} else {print "No\n";};' /i/2.txt
```

No

Comment: @Ilya Makarov, Вы предлагаете вместо скрипта на bash (или sh) использовать скрипт на perl?

Comment: @avp, я просто хотел поделится опытом. Perl это очень удобно.
Например:В файле aa.txt содержатся имена файлов, подписать напротив каждого - есть он или нет:
% cat aa.txt| perl -ne 'chomp;print "$_\t";if (-e $_){print "exists\n";} else {print "not found\n";};'
Вывод:
1.txt exists
2.txt not found